# html table tag not matching closing body tag

Tags: c#

I recently started C# a couple days ago (transitioning from Java) and am writing some codes to practice. This current program reads an xml file and outputs the content in an html table. I use Visual Studios IDE.
I get the error: The 'table' start tag does not match the end tag of 'body'. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace XML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the file name: ");
            String fileName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter output file");
            String outFile = Console.ReadLine();
            XDocument xml =  XDocument.Load(Path.GetFullPath(outFile)); 
            StreamWriter outf = new StreamWriter(Path.GetFullPath(outFile));
            outputHTML(xml,outf);
            outf.Close();
        }

        static void outputHTML(XDocument xml, StreamWriter outf)
        {
            outf.WriteLine("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            outf.WriteLine("<html>");
            outf.WriteLine("<body>");
            outf.WriteLine("<table border='1'>");
            while (xml.Root.HasElements)
            {
                outf.WriteLine("<tr>");
                var products = from  p in xml.Descendants("book")
                               select new
                               {
                                   author = (String)p.Element("author"),
                                   genre = (String)(String)p.Element("genre"),
                                   title = (string)p.Element("title"),
                                   price = (int)p.Element("price"),
                                   publishDate = (String)p.Element("publish_date"),
                                   Descrip = (String)p.Element(" ")
                               };
                foreach (var product in products)
                {
                    outf.WriteLine("<td>");
                    outf.WriteLine(product.author);
                    outf.WriteLine("</td>");

                    outf.WriteLine("<td>");
                    outf.WriteLine(product.title);
                    outf.WriteLine("</td>");

                    outf.WriteLine("<td>");
                    outf.WriteLine(product.genre);
                    outf.WriteLine("</td>");

                    outf.WriteLine("<td>");
                    outf.WriteLine(product.price);
                    outf.WriteLine("</td>");

                    outf.WriteLine("<td>");
                    outf.WriteLine(product.publishDate);
                    outf.WriteLine("</td>");

                    outf.WriteLine("<td>");
                    outf.WriteLine(product.Descrip);
                    outf.WriteLine("</td>");


                }
                outf.WriteLine("</tr>");
            }
            outf.WriteLine("</table>");
            outf.WriteLine("</body>");
            outf.WriteLine("</html>");
        }
    }
}
```

***Also, if anyone could recommend any programs to write to practice C#, that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Just a note (not the cause of your issue): I imagine you want one row per product, so move your `tr` creation inside the product `foreach`.

Comment: Can you post what your XML looks like? Also why do you have a `while` loop going (that looks to never end)? And post the output you get as a result as well.

Comment: @gunr2171...i wasnt sure how to keep the porgram looping while there were still nodes. the output doesnt run becasue i get a run time error. <catalog><book id="bk101"><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author><title>XML Developer's Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>44.95</price><publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date><description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description></book>

Comment: @TimMedora...yes thank you...also nay ideas on issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, for the love of god, don't write your own Html (or xml either). You are going to run into ALL sorts of problems, from encoding to mis-matching tags. Use the [`HTML Agility Pack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to do all the formatting for you.

```
public string CreateHTML(XElement sourceXML)
{
    //make the Html Agility Pack object
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

    //parse through your xml
    var products = sourceXML.Descendants("book")
        .Select(x => new
        {
            author = x.Element("author").Value,
            genre = x.Element("genre").Value,
            title = x.Element("title").Value,
            price = x.Element("price").Value,
            publishDate = x.Element("publish_date").Value,
            descrip = x.Element("description"),
        });

    //make and populate your table node
    HtmlNode tableNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<table border='1'>");

    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        tableNode.AppendChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode("<td>" + product.author + "</td>"));
        tableNode.AppendChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode("<td>" + product.genre + "</td>"));
        ....
    }

    //create the html root and append the table node
    doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode("<html><body>"));
    doc.DocumentNode.Element("html").Element("body").AppendChild(tableNode);

    return doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
XElement sourceXML = XElement.Load(Path.GetFullPath(outFile));
string html = CreateHTML(sourceXML);
```

Comment: @gunr2171...The 'table' start tag on line 4 position 2 does not match the end tag of 'body'. Line 461, position 3. still getting this even after agility pack...

Comment: @XcutionX, update your question with the exact html output you are getting.